# simple question about integration by parts

Tags: integration

I'm trying to see if I understood the integration by parts correctly. By setting $u(t) = a(t)$ and $dv(t) = b(t)dt$, the integral by part gives $\int_0^k a(t) b(t) dt = u(k)v(k) - u(0)v(0) - \int_0^k v(t) du(t)$. Since $v(t) = \int_0^t b(t') dt'$, is this integral become
\begin{align}
\int_0^k a(t) b(t) dt &= a(k)\int_0^k b(t)dt - a(0) \int_0^0 b(t) dt - \int_0^k \Big(\int_0^t b(t') dt'\Big) a'(t)dt\\
& = a(k)\int_0^k b(t)dt - \int_0^k \Big(\int_0^t b(t') dt'\Big) a'(t)dt?
\end{align}

or, is it:
\begin{align}
a(t) \Big(\int b(t)dt\Big)_{t=0}^{t=k} - \int_0^k \Big(\int b(t) dt\Big) a'(t) dt?
\end{align}

Comment: Are the derivatives of both sides equal?  And do they have the same value at any point?  If the answers are yes, then what can you conclude?

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to use $t'$ for the name of a new variable. Specially when derivatives are involved. I'd choose another letter like $s$. Notation is important for clarity.

Comment: And just to be clear. $v(t)$ needs not to be exactly equal to $\int_0^t b(s) ds$. It can be *any* antiderivative of $b(t)$.

Comment: I added one additional line in the post. Did you mean by that?